# How to communicate between a parent/child component when parent's children dynamically defined via `children` from a grandparent component?

Tags: reactjs

So, in React, we know that we can have children communicate with parents via a callback like this:

```
Child = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onAction.bind(null, this.props.name)}>Child button</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
});

Parent = React.createClass({
  handleChildAction(name) {
    alert(`Child button ${name} clicked`);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child name="robot1" onAction={this.handleChildAction} />
      </div>
    )
  }  
});
```

But I'm unclear on how there can be 2-way communication between parent/children in this kind of format:

```
Container = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child name="robot1" />
        <Child name="robot2" />
      </Parent>
    )
  }
});
```

How can I get `Parent` to send information down to the children, and to have `Child` send info up?

Comment: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html

Comment: Nice! That's a nice shortcut from the usual callback structure, but it doesn't explain how to allow `Parent` to talk to the children in scenario #2 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a situation I generally try to avoid, but it can be useful [in certain situations](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/360fcebba4fb8d71d09272e2b66f318c4bf498af/src/ListGroup.js#L36-L38) when parents represent some container of a specific type of children, or should present some other kind of abstraction.

When you find it necessary, you can utilize [mapping over `this.props.children`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.children.map) inside `Parent` [along with `React.cloneElement`](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.cloneelement) to pass them additional props. Remember you should treat `this.props.children` as opaque, and only iterate them via the `React.Children` helpers. For example:

```javascript
var Child = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Child button</button>
      </div>
    )
  },

  handleClick(e) {
    this.props.onAction(this.props.name);
  }
});

var Parent = React.createClass({
  handleChildAction(name) {
    alert(`Child button ${name} clicked`);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{React.Children.map(this.props.children, this.renderChild)}</div>
    )
  },

  renderChild(child) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {onAction: this.handleChildAction});
  }
});

var Container = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <Parent>
        <Child name="robot1" />
        <Child name="robot2" />
      </Parent>
    );
  }
});
```

Here's [a working JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mijune/edit?js,output) that demonstrates the technique: https://jsbin.com/mijune/edit?js,output

Comment: I noticed within the `Container` component, you're passing to `Child` the following prop: `onAction={this.handleChildAction}`, but there's no `handleChildAction` method in the `Container` prop. Or does `this` refer to the `Parent`?

Comment: Ah I get it now. Looks like you don't even need `onAction={this.handleChildAction}` in the `Container` component. I removed those, and it still works fine since you're adding the handler prop when you clone the children.

Comment: @ffxsam Ah yes, that is a typo. I will fix!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the grandparent. How about this.

```
Child = React.createClass({
    handleAction(name) {
        this.props.onAction(this.props.name);
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleAction}>Child button</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

Parent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() { return {data: ''}; },
    handleChildAction(name) {
        alert(`Child button ${name} clicked`);
        this.props.grandParentAction(data);
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child name="robot1" onAction={this.handleChildAction} parentData={this.props.grandParentData} />
            </div>
        )
    }  
});

GrandParent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() { return {data: ''}; },
    handleParentAction(name) {
        alert(`Parent passed ${name}`);
        this.setState({data: 'newData'});
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Child name="robot1" onAction={this.handleChildAction} parentData={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        )
    }  
});
```

Comment: It does, but `Parent` can't contain specific, hardcoded children. `Parent` is contained by a larger component that will define what the children are.

Comment: Then the parent needs to pass the state to its parent and send its props rather than its state to the children.

Comment: Or pass the grandparent handler to the child.